# How do i plot multiple plots in a single rectangular grid in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have plotted 4 bargraphs showing the highest number of 4's,6's,2's,1's scored by the batsman using the following code:

```
for i in [6,4,2,1]:
ax=delivery[delivery['batsman_runs']==i].batsman.value_counts()[:10].plot.bar(width=0.8)
for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+0.10, p.get_height()+1))
mlt.show()
```

Now this method plots the bargraphs one below the other. How do i plot these bargraphs side by side to each other ina grid of (2x2)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [pyplot.subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots). In the example below I use pyplot as plt.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots((2,2))
arr = [6,4,2,1]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i  < 2:
        axes[0][i].bar(i, delivery[delivery['batsman_runs']==arr [i]].batsman.value_counts()[:10],  0.8)
    else:
        axes[1][i - 2].bar(i, delivery[delivery['batsman_runs']==arr [i]].batsman.value_counts()[:10], 0.8)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use matplotlib's subplot:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html